# Android jar assets

Tags: android

I know that when I compile android to a jar, I don;t get the resources inside the jar, but what about assets? lets say I got fonts in my assets folder, is it possible to put them in the jar and address them like on a normal APK?

```
 Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/somefont.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, assets are not supported either by JARs or by Android library projects at this time.

Comment: any suggestion about load fonts from server?

Comment: @ChenKinnrot: Download the font file and use `Typeface.createFromFile()`.